# AssertionError at /cart/ Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Tags: jquery, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, e-commerce

I want to refactor or integrate some old Django code from an old Django project. Everything was ok until the add to cart option or view. I don't know if there is anything I missed because I just following to code not the working procedure or steps. It's so straight forward to follow. But I got stack right now.

cart models views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
from django.urls  import reverse

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status

from . import models
from products import models as product_models


class CartCreateView(TemplateView, APIView):
    """ add item to cart request handler """
    template_name = 'carts/view.html'

    @staticmethod
    def _process_cart(item_id, quantity, delete, request):
        cart = None
        is_deleted = False
        if 'cart_id' not in request.session:
            cart = models.Cart.objects.create()
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id
        if cart == None:
            cart = models.Cart.objects.get(id=request.session['cart_id'])
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            cart.user = request.user
            cart.save()
        product_models.Variation.objects.get(id=item_id)
        cart_item, created = models.CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, item_id=item_id)
        if created or quantity != 1:
            cart_item.quantity = quantity
        else:
            cart_item.quantity += 1;
        if delete in ['y','yes', 'true', 'True']:
            is_deleted = True
            cart_item.delete()
        else:
            cart_item.save()
        return cart, is_deleted, cart_item

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            item_id = request.GET.get('item')
            quantity = request.GET.get('qty', 1)
            delete = request.GET.get('delete', 'n')
            cart, is_deleted, cart_item = self._process_cart(item_id, int(quantity), delete, request)
            cart_count = cart.total_count
            request.session['cart_count'] = cart_count
            return Response({'success': True,
             'deleted': is_deleted,
              'count': cart.count,
              'item_total': cart_item.item_total,
              'cart_price': cart.cart_price,
              'cart_count': cart_count}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)


class CartDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'carts/view.html'

    def get(self, request):
        if 'cart_id' not in request.session:
            return redirect('/')
        cart = models.Cart.objects.get(id=request.session['cart_id'])
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'object': cart })
```

here is my template where there is a button and some jquery implementation which should work when I clicked on the button. But the above error occurs.

Maybe the problem is with using APIVIew and django_rest framework. I am not familiar with DRF yet. Please suggest me if you think the desired result can achieve with a function-based view or anything different from this.

Here is my template product_page.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block jquery%}

    window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
    }


  function setPrice(){
    var price = $('.variation-select option:selected').data('price');
    var salePrice = $('.variation-select option:selected').data('sale-price');
    if(salePrice && salePrice !== 'None'){
        $('#price').html(` <h3>${salePrice}<small style="color:red;text-decoration:line-through;">${price}</small><h3>`);
    }
    else{
        $('#price').text(price);
    }
  }

    $('.variation-select').change(function(){
        setPrice();
    })


$('#add-to-cart').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('#cart-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'create_cart' %}" + '?' + formData,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('#cart-count-badge').text(response.cart_count);
            $('.container.flash-msg').fadeIn();
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('.container.flash-msg').fadeOut();
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(response, error){

        }
    });
});

  {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<style>
    .flash-msg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 23px;
        z-index: 2000;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
</style>


<div class="container flash-msg">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-8">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
          <strong>Item added to cart</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
        <h3>{{product.title}}</h3>
        {% if product.get_image_url %}
            <div>
                <img src="{{product.get_image_url}}" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div>
            <p class="lead">{{product.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <form id="cart-form" method="GET" action="{% url 'create_cart' %}"> 
        <!-- show product variation -->
        {% if product.variation_set.all.count > 1 %}
            <h3 id="price">{{product.variation_set.first.price}}
                {% if product.variation_set.first.sale_price %}
                    <small id="sale-price" style="color:red;text-decoration:line-through;">{{product.variation_set.first.sale_price}}</small>       
                {% endif %}
            </h3>
            <select name="item" class="form-control variation-select"> 
            {% for variation in product.variation_set.all %}
                <option data-sale-price="{{variation.sale_price}}" data-price="{{variation.price}}" value="{{variation.id}}">{{variation}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
        {% else %}
            <h3 id="price">{{product.variation_set.first.price}}</h3>
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="{{product.variation_set.first.id}}" />
        {% endif %}
        <br>
        <button id="add-to-cart" class="btn btn-primary" href="">Add To Cart</button>
    </form>
        <br>
        <br>

        {% if related_products %}
            <h4>Related products</h4>
            <div class="row">
                {% for product in related_products %}
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        {% include "products/product_thumbnail.html" with product=product %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: On exception you just print the error and don't return anything from your `get` method. You need to return some kind of response

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a HTTP Response even when you got an exception. Change your `get`method like this:

```
def get(self, request):
    try:
        # rest of your method
        # ... ...
    except Exception as error:
        Response({'success': False}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was in

```
"if request.user.is_authenticated():"
```

It will be **`if request.user.is_authenticated:`** . The parenthesis was the culprit. Thanks, everyone for their help.